# Why a UEFI protocol header file defines both a macro and an external global variable for a single protocol GUID?

Tags: c, macros, uefi

I am new to UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) development. And I am using the EDK (EFI Development Kit).

To create a new protocol, we need to give the protocol a GUID. For example, in the header file for `BlockIO` protocol, we can see this:

(MdePkg\Include\BlockIo.h)

The macro:
[image]

The global variable:

[image]

And in the package declaration file `MdePkg.dec`:

[image]

Why do we need 3 of these to give a protocol a GUID?

(Maybe this question is related to C language specifics, so I add the `c` and `macros` tags, too.)

Comment: I believe it's just for clarity. Define shows you what the actual GUID value assigned and you don't have to go to UEFI Protocol manual/doc to see what GUID is assigned to that protocol. If you need to know it for some reason. External variable is declared in h-file but initialized/assigned in c-file. For example, In my case, I have only headers and no source but I can see the actual GUID right where the global external variable is declared.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable can be used only by drivers that link against the object where it is defined (`BlockIo.c` in your case). I think the macro is defined in the header file so that drivers that don't link with that object can use the GUID from the macro.